# Nav links not hiding when side menu div closes to 0px

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidebar

I am trying to create a css side menu but when I close the menu, setting div container width to 0, the links are still visible.

Here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/atLvp6k7/

Interestingly, when I set the menu to the right of the screen I do not have the same problem. Do I need to add margin properties to the a items?

```
<div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">  
   <img id="close-side" src="https://floraisabelle.com/assets/images/hamburger-menu.png?v=aa3f825eb7" alt="">
    <a class="" href="#">Hi</a>
    <a class="" href="#">Hi</a>
    <a class="" href="#">Hi</a>
    <a class="" href="#">Hi</a>
</div>

var isOpen = false;
document.getElementById('close-side').addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (isOpen) {
        document.getElementById("side-menu").style.width = "0px";
        document.getElementById("close-side").style.marginLeft = "0px";
        isOpen = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("side-menu").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("close-side").style.marginLeft = "181px";
        isOpen = true;
    } 
})

.side-nav {
  transition: .5s;
  height: 100%;
  width:0;
  background-color: rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.1);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1; 
}

#close-side {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transition: linear .5s;
  position: fixed; 
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: Your issue is that you're attempting to hide the sidebar by reducing it's width. That just causes everything inside it to reposition and eventually overflow. You don't see this happening on the right because everything is flowing outside the viewport, but it will still be happening behind the scenes. You should instead hide it by modifying it's `left:` position to position it off-screen.

Comment: Thanks for that. Makes sense, I will set overflow-x to hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**css**

```
.side-hidden a {
   display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="side-menu" class="side-nav side-hidden">
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 var isOpen = false;
 document.getElementById('close-side').addEventListener("click", function(){
 if (isOpen) {
        document.getElementById("side-menu").classList.add('side-hidden');
        document.getElementById("side-menu").style.width = "0px";
        document.getElementById("close-side").style.marginLeft = "0px";
        isOpen = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("side-menu").classList.remove('side-hidden');
        document.getElementById("side-menu").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("close-side").style.marginLeft = "181px";
        isOpen = true;
    } 
})
```

I have updated your fiddle also
https://jsfiddle.net/atLvp6k7/1/

there is no need for isOpen Variable

```
if(document.getElementById("side-menu").classList.contains('side-hidden')){
  alert('isClosed');
}else{
   alert('isOpen');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, i dont think so.

Comment: Sure thanks, can you upvote? Thought a down vote for that was a touch harsh ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you can change the margin of the sidebar instead of width....

here is how to do it -

```
document.getElementById('close-side').addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (isOpen) {
        document.getElementById("close-side").style.marginLeft = "-100px";
        isOpen = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("close-side").style.marginLeft = "0px";
        isOpen = true;
    } 
})
```

and place the button (close-side) outside the sidebar div

```
<img id="close-side" src="https://floraisabelle.com/assets/images/hamburger-menu.png?v=aa3f825eb7" alt="">

<div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">  
    <a class="" href="#">Hi</a>
    <a class="" href="#">Hi</a>
    <a class="" href="#">Hi</a>
    <a class="" href="#">Hi</a>
</div>
```

now apply following css for the transition effect -

```
.side-nav
{
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```